# Set-AzureRmSqlDatabase is failing

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-automation

It seems the Azure Run As Account no longer is working for any scripts.  We've made no changes to it, the cert expires in 2018.  This seems to be the cause but I do not have a solution to it.

Having trouble running `Set-AzureRmSqlDatabase -ResourceGroupName "$RGName" -DatabaseName "$DBName" -ServerName "$ServerName" -Edition $Edition -ServiceObjective $DBLevel` as it generates this error:

```
Set-AzureRmSqlDatabase : Run Login-AzureRmAccount to login.
At line:56 char:1
+ Set-AzureRmSqlDatabase -ResourceGroupName "$RGName" -DatabaseName "$D ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Set-AzureRmSqlDatabase], PSInvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperation,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Sql.Database.Cmdlet.SetAzureSqlDatabase
```

I thought the `Add-AzureRmAccount` logs in the session. The other issue I've researched could be the values for the parameters.  Sample values are:

`$RGName: my-rg`

`$Edition: Standard`

`$ServerName: my-db-server`  // not the fully qualified one but I tried it too

`$DBName: my-db`

`$DBLevel: S0`

The same top part works fine on another script to resize an application plan.

Code:

```
Param
     (
         [Parameter (Mandatory= $true)]
         [String] $RGName,

         [Parameter (Mandatory= $false)]
         [String] $Edition="Standard",

         [Parameter (Mandatory= $true)]
         [String] $ServerName,

         [Parameter (Mandatory= $true)]
         [String] $DBName,

         [Parameter (Mandatory= $true)]
         [String] $DBLevel,

         [Parameter (Mandatory= $false)]
         [String] $SubId = "mysub"
     )
$connectionName = "AzureRunAsConnection"

try
{
    # Get the connection "AzureRunAsConnection "
    $servicePrincipalConnection=Get-AutomationConnection -Name $connectionName         

    "Logging in to Azure..."
    Add-AzureRmAccount `
        -ServicePrincipal `
        -TenantId $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantId `
        -ApplicationId $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId `
        -CertificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint 
}
catch {
    if (!$servicePrincipalConnection)
    {
        $ErrorMessage = "Connection $connectionName not found."
        throw $ErrorMessage
    } else{
        Write-Error -Message $_.Exception
        throw $_.Exception
    }
}

Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId $SubId

Set-AzureRmSqlDatabase -ResourceGroupName "$RGName" -DatabaseName "$DBName" -ServerName "$ServerName" -Edition $Edition -RequestedServiceObjectiveName $DBLevel
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not signed in into azure:

```
Set-AzureRmSqlDatabase : Run Login-AzureRmAccount to login
```

Logon and try again.

It seems you Add-AzureRmAccount fails. Remove the try catch and have a look at the return value.

Comment: Okay, I confirmed the run as account cert expires in 2018.  Scripts that ran prior are now failing based on this login which I don't know how to address.

Comment: It works now without me making any changes.  I'll give you credit for the answer.  I submitted a support ticket and we'll see what they say.